# Cannot convert Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<T> to Linq.IQueryable<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Trying to add an `orderby` statement to my generic repository method and getting the below error. Not sure why as it seems I am able to add a .OrderBy to an IQueryable in other cases.

What am I missing?

Getting Error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'

Code Snippet (some parts removed):

```
public class QuickbooksRespository<TEntity>
         where TEntity : class, Intuit.Ipp.Data.IEntity, new()
    {
    public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll(
        int page, int pageSize,
        Func<TEntity, object> orderbyascending = null,
        Func<TEntity, object> orderbydescending = null)
    {
        int skip = Math.Max(pageSize * (page - 1), 0);

        IQueryable<TEntity> results = _qbQueryService
                .Select(all => all);

        if (orderbyascending != null)
        {
            results = results.OrderBy(orderbyascending);
        }

        if (orderbydescending != null)
        {
            results = results.OrderByDescending(orderbydescending);
        }

        return results
                .Skip(skip)
                .Take(pageSize);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Because you're providing `Func<...>` delegate, `IEnumerable.OrderBy` extension method is chosen. Change your method parameters to `Expression<Func<...>>`:

```
public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll(
    int page, int pageSize,
    Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> orderbyascending = null,
    Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> orderbydescending = null)
```

It will make `IQueryable.OrderBy()` method to be choose instead of `IEnumerable.OrderBy()` when you actually call `OrderBy()` later.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! Was pulling my hair out. Don't have much experience with Expressions and Functions like this yet.

Comment: I was going crazy about this, thanks : )